# How to calculate mean of matrix based on column value

Tags: arrays, matlab, mean

I have B matrix of N*4 dim. I want calculate the mean of the matrix based on last column values. Last column has repeated values in the range of 1 to 3. I want to calculate the mean of all rows whose last column have same value.
I am using this command:

```
l(it:,)=mean(B(i,:))
```

where `it` ranges from 1 to 3 in the loop and `i` has all the indices of rows whose last column=1.When I run this code I get `Sub scripted assignment dimension mismatch error`. Can anyone point out what is wrong in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example data:

```
B = [ 0.4000    0.3000    0.2000    1.0000
      0.3000    0.2000    0.1000    2.0000
      0.7000    0.8000    0.6000    1.0000
      0.3000    0.4000    0.8000    2.0000
      0.7000    0.5000    0.5000    3.0000
      0.1000    0.3000    0.9000    3.0000
      0.6000    0.4000    0.5000    1.0000 ];
```

Two possible approaches:

1. Using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html):

   ```
   result = NaN(3,3);
   for k = 1:3
       result(k,:) = mean(B(B(:,4)==k,1:3));
   end
   ```
2. Using [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

   ```
   result = NaN(3,3);
   for k = 1:3
       result(:,k) = accumarray(B(:,4), B(:,k), [], @mean, NaN);
   end
   ```

With the example data, either of the above gives

```
result =
    0.5667    0.5000    0.4333
    0.3000    0.3000    0.4500
    0.4000    0.4000    0.7000
```

Comment: Even when i try to run your code i get subscripted assignment dimension mismatch . What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: I am not able to understand this line result(k,:) = mean(B(B(:,4)==k,1:3)); can u please explain??

Comment: When I increase the number of columns of the matrix and changed the dim of result , I am getting Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: @KeerthanaPraveen That line computes the mean of all rows that have the value `k` in last column

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not the clearest, but I **think** I know what you are trying to do.

You say that `i` contains the indices of the rows of interest for each value 1,2,3 so I am assuming that you require

```
 mean_k = mean(mean((B(i,:)))
```

for each k = 1,2,3. Obviously you must be recalculating `i` each time you iterate over 1,2,3 when identifying the relevant rows of interest.

The `mean` function when called on a matrix does not return a scalar, it returns a row vector whose elements are the mean of each column of the matrix. Therefore to get the mean, you need to call `mean` again on the result.

Bear in mind that this also includes the final column value (that you are using for classification) in your overall mean calculations