# How to calculate mean of grouped dataframe?

Tags: r

I am trying to split a dataframe based on `participant_number` then calculate the grand mean of the specific columns `Happiness` and `Joy` (excluding column `Lolz`). Why does taking the mean of the column means result in:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1L)  :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1L)  :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(participant_number=c(1,1,1,2,2),Happiness=c(3,4,2,1,3),Joy=c(1,2,3,5,4),Lolz=c(3,3,3,3,3))

df%>%group_by(participant_number)%>%
select(Happiness,Joy)%>%
mutate(emoMean=mean(colMeans))

> df
  participant_number Happiness Joy Lolz
1                  1         3   1    3
2                  1         4   2    3
3                  1         2   3    3
4                  2         1   5    3
5                  2         3   4    3
```

GOAL

```
emoMean
participant_number ... emoMean
1                      2.5 (3+1+4+2+2+3)/6 #Note that this value does not include participant_number
1                      2.5
1                      2.5
2                      6.5
2                      6.5
```

Notes:

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914161/how-to-calculate-mean-of-matrix-based-on-column-value) as a potential solution but got completely lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific case, you can just add the two columns together, take the mean and then divide it by two, since the two columns always have the same count:

```
df %>% group_by(participant_number) %>% mutate(emoMean = mean(Happiness + Joy)/2)

Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
Groups: participant_number [2]

  participant_number Happiness   Joy  Lolz emoMean
               <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1                  1         3     1     3    2.50
2                  1         4     2     3    2.50
3                  1         2     3     3    2.50
4                  2         1     5     3    3.25
5                  2         3     4     3    3.25
```

*Note:* At the mean time, by your definition of the mean of the first group, I think for the second group, it should be 3.25 instead of 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to plyr:

```
df<data.frame(participant_number=c(1,1,1,2,2),Happiness=c(3,4,2,1,3),Joy=c(1,2,3,5,4),Lolz=c(3,3,3,3,3))

df$mean <- ave(apply(df[,2:3],1,mean, na.rm=TRUE), df$participant_number )
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, emoMean := mean(Happiness + Joy)/2 , by = participant_number]
```

If there are many columns to do the `sum`, one option is `Reduce`

```
 nm1 <- names(df)[2:3]
 setDT(df)[, emoMean := Reduce(`+`, .SD)/length(nm1), 
                   by = participant_number, .SDcols = nm1]
```